# How to run "docker/compose" container on RPi3?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have pull the image https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose/
`docker pull docker/compose`

But how can I run it to build my images on Raspberry Pi/rpi3?

Comment: Why not just run `docker-compose up`?

Comment: Sorry @030, I forgot to metion that I want to run it on a RPi3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to this reply](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose/) it should run by issuing:

> ```
> docker run -ti --rm -v `pwd`/docker-compose.yaml:/docker-compose.yml -v
> /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker/compose:1.16.1 up
> ```